# Buttons to change only when the it's checkbox is checked and the submit button is clicked in react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, algorithm

In my small react project, i have many input with type checkboxes and each checkbox has a button attached to them. And theres a submit button also. The way it's supposed to work is that when any of the checkbox is checked and the submit button is clicked, the button attached to that particular checkbox changes to a different button. and when multiple checkboxes are also selected and the submit button is clicked, all the selected checkboxes button will change to a different button. Presently, what I have is that as soon as i checked the box the button is changing instead of waiting till i click the submit button. and the box also go back to other button immediately it's unchecked. I really need to know what I'm doing wrong.

my codesandbox here [codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-feather-s0o7r?file=/src/App.js)

my code also

App.js

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

import "./styles.css";
import "./Defaultdata";
import Defaultdata from "./Defaultdata";

export default function App() {
  const inputEl = useRef("");


  const [sampledata, setsampledata] = useState({
    type_1: "watch",
    id: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(newdatatoshow);
  }, [sampledata]);

 
  const [click, setclick] = useState(false);
  const [clcikeditem, setclcikeditem] = useState([]);
const [id, setid] = useState('')
const [upd, setupd] = useState([])
 

  const handlesubmit2 = (e) => {
    if (
      sampledata.id.includes(id) 
    ) {
      setclick(true);
    } else {
      setclick(false);
    }

    //console.log(sampledata.id.map(d => d === upd.includes(id)))

    
  };


  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log(sampledata);
    
    console.log(clcikeditem, 'clicked item')
  }, [clcikeditem, sampledata]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <button onClick={handlesubmit2}>Submit</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th></th>
          <th>Item 1</th>
          <th></th>
        
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {Defaultdata.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  {" "}
                  <span
                    onClick={(e) => {
                      // setcheckboxstate(e.target.checked);
                      setsampledata({
                        ...sampledata,
                        id: [...sampledata.id, item.id]
                      });
                      setclcikeditem(sampledata.id);
                      if (!e.target.checked) {
                        setsampledata({
                          ...sampledata,
                          id: sampledata.id.filter(function (n) {
                            return n !== item.id;
                          })
                        });
                      }
                      setid(item.id)
                      setupd([...sampledata.id, id])
                      // console.log(sampledata.id.includes("NG3088568879"));
                    }}
                  >
                    {" "}
                    <input type="checkbox" ref={inputEl} />{" "}
                  </span>{" "}
                </td>

                <tr>
                  <td>{item.id}</td>
                  {  click  && sampledata.id.includes(item.id) ? <button>Yes</button> : <button>no</button>}
                </tr>
               
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

DefaultData

```
const Defaultdata = [
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    id: "7857699961",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25 - 2021-11-14",
    distance: "22.8 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:36:54",
    watched: "yes",
    mode: "car"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "3 days ago",
    id: "8358962006",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-18 - 2021-10-24",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-22 16:54:12",
    mode: "truck"
  },
  {
    date_listed: "4 hours ago",
    id: "8146462294",
    delivery_time_frame: "2021-10-25",
    distance: "4.3 km",
    time_stamp: "2021-10-25 16:12:32",
    mode: "bike"
  }
];



export default Defaultdata
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to solve the multiple checkboxes' problem in an imperative manner and forget the power of functional approach that React offers

you can render a checkbox for each item in the array

one => one match (each item has its own checkbox)

```js
          {Defaultdata.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <tr key={index}>
                <td>
                  <input
                    id={item.id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                       ...
                    }}
                  />

                  <label htmlFor={item.id}>{item.id}</label>
                </td>
               ...
              </tr>
            );
          })}
```

for the on change event handler you just need to check `event.target.checked` to store the checked item or remove it, you almost get it, but I've just removed any unnecessary state changes too

```js
                  <input
                    id={item.id}
                    type="checkbox"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.target.checked) {
                        setSampleData({
                          ...sampleData,
                          ids: [...sampleData.ids, item.id]
                        });
                      } else {
                        setSampleData({
                          ...sampleData,
                          ids: sampleData.ids.filter(function (id) {
                            return id !== item.id;
                          })
                        });
                      }
                    }}
                  />
```

and for the `isClicked` state I've deleted because you can calculate immediately based on the list of ids you have in the state using a function that is called for each item id accordingly

```js
  function isClicked(id) {
    return Boolean(sampleData.ids.find((sampleId) => sampleId === id));
  }
```

I've tried to conclude most of the logic of your UI based on what you described and what you wrote in the sandbox, but I may have something that you don't want, so try to understand the idea of the code and change it to fit into your use case.

Here's the final updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-banach-dx0f3?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you for your quick response but I only want the buttons to change when the submit button is clicked. In your code the buttons are changing as you are checking the boxes but that's not the way i want it. When you select any of the items or many, the buttons of the selected items won't change until you clcik on the submit button. @Mhd Louay Al-osh